# THREE.js loader callbacks not working on real server

Tags: javascript, callback, three.js

Firstly, here's the code I'm referring to:

```
    ObjMtlLoad: function (path, objName, mtlName, context, rotateRads = 0) {
    console.log("Loading...");
    //declare callback function for printing out download progress
    var onProgress = function (xhr) {
        if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
            //calculate and output progress
            var percentComplete = (xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100;
            console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + "% downloaded " + objName);
            if (xhr.loaded == xhr.total) {
                console.log("loaded");
                $("#loadingDisplay").css({
                    opacity: 0
                });
            }
        }
    };
    //declare callback function for when an error occurs
    var onError = function (xhr) {
        console.log("Error: " + xhr);
    };

        //instantiate a MTLLoader object
    var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    //set the base path
    mtlLoader.setPath(path);
    //load the mtl file
    mtlLoader.load(mtlName, function (materials) {
        materials.preload();
        //instantiate a OBJLoader object
        var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        //apply the mtl file to the obj
        objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
        //set the base path
        objLoader.setPath(path);
        //load the objfile
        objLoader.load(objName, function (object) {
            //set position to the center
            object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            //rotate if requested
            object.rotateX(rotateRads);
            //add to scene
            context.scene.add(object);
        }, onProgress, onError);
    });
}
```

What should happen is the onProgress function gets called by the loader and prints out the current progress and, if finished, removes the 'loading' overlay. This all works fine when running on the local debugging server created by [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), and the following output is produced:
[image: correct output]

However, when uploaded to my web server, none of this happens, everything actually loads asynchronously but nothing gets printed out and the callbacks seemingly aren't called at all. Causing the 'loading' overlay to remain even once the content has loaded beneath it. This is the console output when viewed on the server:

[image: unexpected output]

Comment: did you look to see if any resources were missing?  Look at the network pane in your dom inspector to make sure Avent.obj and all the other resources are on the server and successfully requested.

Comment: @DanFarrell Yep, all the resources load successfully in te network pane. The 3D model is visible after it's loaded through the semi-transparent overlay.

Comment: Which version are you using? There was a bug with this stuff that got fixed recently: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9797

Comment: @griffin2000 I'm using a version from after that bug was fixed so I don't think it's that